# Session server side or client side(accessible or not)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, client-side, server-side

I'm saving some of basic user informations in Session on my Asp.net MVC application. How safe is to save UserGroup in there and access it to see if user is Administrator or normal User?

I am, before running any action, asking if a user is administrator or not, *directly from database*, but still, I would like to know if the way above is safe.

Also, I am using FormsAuthentication, if that changes anything.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Sorry ! I am still not following what your question is. For the question in your title, Session data is stored in the server for that user(browser session)

Comment: Yes, thats what I was asking. If it was stored on client side, there could probably be a way to edit it, so user can change their User Information. There would not be a problem I was storing FirstName, LastName..etc. But I would like to keep info about the user if he is Normal user or Administrator. If he could change session, he could set his UserGroup to Administrator and do stuff he is not allowed to do, which is not safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using session for storing userInfo is not a risky affair, as this information will not be passed onto clientside ever.
UserAccessRights would be something you would be checking at every action so it is good to keep that in session instead of retrieving it from DB everytime.
only problem is that when your userrights is updated you need to update session as well to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks, that why I asked, so I don't have to call DB all the time when I need some basic info. Thanks again.